# Get a list of the instances in a type class in Haskell

Tags: haskell, introspection

Is there a way to programmatically get a list of instances of a type class?

It strikes me that the compiler must know this information in order to type check and compile the code, so is there some way to tell the compiler: hey, you know those instances of that class, please put a list of them right here (as strings or whatever some representation of them).

Comment: Actually, the compiler does not know which instances are defined. The only thing it can do, is checking whether a type is instance of a typeclass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can generate the instances in scope for a given type class using Template Haskell.

```
import Language.Haskell.TH

-- get a list of instances
getInstances :: Name -> Q [ClassInstance]
getInstances typ = do
  ClassI _ instances <- reify typ
  return instances

-- convert the list of instances into an Exp so they can be displayed in GHCi
showInstances :: Name -> Q Exp
showInstances typ = do
  ins <- getInstances typ
  return . LitE . stringL $ show ins
```

Running this in GHCi:

```
*Main> $(showInstances ''Num)
"[ClassInstance {ci_dfun = GHC.Num.$fNumInteger, ci_tvs = [], ci_cxt = [], ci_cls = GHC.Num.Num, ci_tys = [ConT GHC.Integer.Type.Integer]},ClassInstance {ci_dfun = GHC.Num.$fNumInt, ci_tvs = [], ci_cxt = [], ci_cls = GHC.Num.Num, ci_tys = [ConT GHC.Types.Int]},ClassInstance {ci_dfun = GHC.Float.$fNumFloat, ci_tvs = [], ci_cxt = [], ci_cls = GHC.Num.Num, ci_tys = [ConT GHC.Types.Float]},ClassInstance {ci_dfun = GHC.Float.$fNumDouble, ci_tvs = [], ci_cxt = [], ci_cls = GHC.Num.Num, ci_tys = [ConT GHC.Types.Double]}]"
```

Another useful technique is showing all instances in scope for a given type class using GHCi.

```
Prelude> :info Num
class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  (*) :: a -> a -> a
  (-) :: a -> a -> a
  negate :: a -> a
  abs :: a -> a
  signum :: a -> a
  fromInteger :: Integer -> a
    -- Defined in GHC.Num
instance Num Integer -- Defined in GHC.Num
instance Num Int -- Defined in GHC.Num
instance Num Float -- Defined in GHC.Float
instance Num Double -- Defined in GHC.Float
```

Edit: The important thing to know is that the compiler is only aware of type classes in scope in any given module (or at the ghci prompt, etc.).  So if you call the `showInstances` TH function with no imports, you'll only get instances from the Prelude.  If you have other modules in scope, e.g. Data.Word, then you'll see all those instances too.

Comment: It appears this only works for GHC 7 and TH 2.5. Trying to do this in TH 2.4.0.1 doesn't seem to give me what I want. Is this a new feature then?

Comment: I'm running GHC 7.6.3. Here's an update to the answer: `[ClassInstance]` is now `[InstanceDec]`. Also, I needed to run `:set -XTemplateHaskell` in GHCi in order to duplicate the example.

Answer (score 7):

See the template haskell documentation: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.5.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html

Using `reify`, you can get an Info record, which for a class includes its list of instances. You can also use `isClassInstance` and `classInstances` directly.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to run into a lot of problems as soon as you get instance declarations like

```
instance Eq a => Eq [a] where
    [] == [] = True
    (x:xs) == (y:ys) = x == y && xs == ys
    _ == _ = False
```

and

```
instance (Eq a,Eq b) => Eq (a,b) where
    (a1,b1) == (a2,b2) = a1 == a2 && b1 == b2
```

along with a single concrete instance (e.g. `instance Eq Bool`).

You'll get an infinite list of instances for `Eq` - `Bool`,`[Bool]`,`[[Bool]]`,`[[[Bool]]]` and so on, `(Bool,Bool)`, `((Bool,Bool),Bool)`, `(((Bool,Bool),Bool),Bool)` etcetera, along with various combinations of these such as `([((Bool,[Bool]),Bool)],Bool)` and so forth. It's not clear how to represent these in a `String`; even a list of `TypeRep` would require some pretty smart enumeration.

The compiler *can* (try to) deduce whether a type is an instance of `Eq` for any given type, but it doesn't read in all the instance declarations in scope and then just starts deducing all possible instances, since that will never finish!

The important question is of course, what do you need this for?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, it's not possible. I explain you the implementation of typeclasses (for GHC), from it, you can see, that the compiler has no need to know which types are instance of a typeclass. It only has to know, whether a specific type is instance or not.

A typeclass will be translated into a datatype. As an example, let's take `Eq`:

```
class Eq a where
  (==),(/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

The typeclass will be translated into a kind of dictionary, containing all its functions:

```
data Eq a = Eq {
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool,
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
  }
```

Each typeclass constraint is then translated into an extra argument containing the dictionary:

```
elem :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _ [] = False
elem a (x:xs) | x == a    = True
              | otherwise = elem a xs
```

becomes:

```
elem :: Eq a -> a -> [a] -> Bool
elem _  _ [] = False
elem eq a (x:xs) | (==) eq x a = True
                 | otherwise   = elem eq a xs
```

The important thing is, that the dictionary will be passed *at runtime*. Imagine, your project contains many modules. GHC doesn't have to check all the modules for instances, it just has to look up, whether an instance is defined anywhere.

But if you have the source available, I guess an old-style `grep` for the instances would be sufficient.

Comment: Not exactly true.  The compiler only needs to know if a specific type is an instance, however at any time the compiler can enumerate all instances in scope and generate the desired list.  GHCi will do this if you use `:info Num` for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to automatically do this for existing classes.  For your own class and instances thereof you could do it.  You would need to declare everything via Template Haskell (or perhaps the quasi-quoting) and it would automatically generate some strange data structure that encodes the declared instances.  Defining the strange data structure and making Template Haskell do this are details left to whomever has a use case for them.

Perhaps you could add some Template Haskell or other magic to your build to include all the source files as text available at run-time (c.f. program quine).  Then your program would 'grep itself'...